# Porting a C# program to Ubuntu -- accessing framework namespaces?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm porting a C# application that runs on windows to Ubuntu. I've installed VSCode (since VS is not available), and the C# support and C# dev kit, and created my first "hello world" console program on ubuntu per the tutorial below, all is well.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/get-started

But as I started to bring over code from the windows application, the first thing it needed depended on the namespace Microsoft.Extensions.  This gave me a namepsace does not exist error, with no obvious fix.

I'm not sure if I'm running up against my ignorance of VSCode (this is straightforward in Visual Studio) or limitations of Ubuntu .NET support.  Is there a way to add this namespace to my project on Ubuntu, and if so how do I do this within VSCode?

Thanks very much for *any* help.

```
using System.IO;                         // <-- works
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;      // <-- error 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means you haven't included the correct package or used the wrong project template. You don't have to change namespaces

Comment: You need to `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting --version 7.0.1` to add that package to your project.

Comment: "But as I started to bring over code from the windows application" - you need to include the right dependencies as well. At the moment we don't know anything about the Windows application... is it *actually* a GUI, or something else? Have you looked at the dependencies in the project file?

Comment: Did you copy the `csproj` file as well? The package references would be there. If the project is a web or console app you can just copy the entire folder (or clone the repo) to Linux or WSL and build with `dotnet build`

Comment: Oh, thanks Panagiotis... I copied over and used dotnet build in the folder with the SLN file and it seemed to find all *sorts* of missing things for me, thanks!  I think you launched me 75% up the learning curve. :)  There are two errors involving 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop'... does that sound like something unavailable on Ubuntu?